# Breast mesh not moving in pose mode

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, cloth-simulation, pose-mode

I was learning [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVFx7CvfiPc&t=327s) to know how to make the jiggle of breasts, everything was alright until I tried to move the model in pose mode to see breasts jiggling with the body.

However, when I move the chest bone, the breasts did not move with the body, but were jiggling.

Sensitive content

> [image]